# python - predefined builtlin for method name

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

In python, Is there predefined builtin for function name ?

For Example:

1. We have predefined for module name '**name**'.
2. There is built in for file name '**file**'

similarly i am looking for builtin for method name to add it to logging function.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correct, to get the function name, you can use `__name__` of the function. 
 
**E.g**: `function_name.__name__`

You can find more about this over [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/whats-in-a-python-s-name-506262fe61e8/)

Comment: I wanted to put some generic name so that i don't have hardcode the function name everywhere i am putting that code.